# question regarding the usage of split() in java

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I'm trying to split() a line of text and numbers from a .txt file. I need to segregate the different parts of the line so that i could insert it inside a database table. Here's an example line:

```
051500000711000,051500000711000,equal;
```

I already have working code for this line which is:

```
String delimiter = (",|;");
temp = strLine.split(delimiter);
```

but there are times when the sample line would be like this:

```
052000000711000,,,
```

See the missing values? They are missing because the other program that generates this line has null values; that's why it only returned commas.

The question is what should i do with my delimiter so that it would 
read the commas and return it into my split() array as null.

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting.. im new here..

Comment: I've tidied it up. I've noticed `(",|;);` isn't syntactical correct. Feel free to fix that and make any other corrections you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not the delimiter regex that is the problem.  Use [`String.split(regex, limit)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a limit of -1.  The default limit is zero which trims trailing nulls from the String array returned by the splitter.

Read the linked javadoc for the gory details.

Comment: +1 for the -1 :)  Seriously, though, I once did a little survey of which languages needed the -1 to avoid dropping the tailing items and which did not. Got some interesting results; some popular languages did and some did not.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Apache Commons 2.5 StringUtils' [splitPreserveAllTokens](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitPreserveAllTokens%28java.lang.String,%20char%29)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use it. Get [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and use [`Splitter.on(separator).split(string)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) which solves this and other problems nicely.

Comment: No need to go that far.  See my answer.

Comment: Agreed, your answer works, but `String.split` is simply not worth dealing with. Sure, getting a library may be an overkill, but in case of guava, I'd really recommend it.

Comment: "Getting library might be overkill".  Do'ya think?  Stephen C is correct.  PS: Why *did* you mark Shahzeb down?

Comment: I think, he is (and so am I). Indeed, I wrote I agreed with him. And **no, I did NOT downvote any answer here**. Stop accusing me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this regex:

```
String delimiter = ",";
```

Use like this:

```
temp = strLine.replace(";", "").split(delimiter);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it should already pretty much work that way.

If an intermediate value in the list is "null"...
then you'll get an empty string...
which you can simply TREAT as "null".

Here's an example:

import java.io.*;

```
class X
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    // Prompt user to enter something
    String delimiter = ",|;";
    String sLine = "051500000711000,,051500000711000,A,,";
    String[] sOut = sLine.split (delimiter);
    for (int i=0; i < sOut.length; i++)
     System.out.println ("sOut[]=" + sOut[i]);
  }
}

> sOut[]=051500000711000 
> sOut[]= 
> sOut[]=051500000711000 
> sOut[]=A
```